# Dynamically set parameters in define_method

Tags: ruby

I have a class method `::add_method(name, params = {})` that creates an instance method with `define_method`.

I need the parameters of the defined method to be keyword arguments depending on the `params`.

```rb
class Whatever
  def self.add_method(name, params = {})
    # do something with params
    define_method name do |?|
      # some business
    end
  end
end
```

The goal is that when the `::add_method` is called with:

```rb
params = { 
  foo: { required: false, default: 0 },
  bar: { required: true }
}

Whatever.add_method(:hello, params)
```

then it creates this method:

```
def hello(foo: 0, bar:)
  # some business
end
```

Nota bene: this is not the real business, I've over simplified it so the question is easier to understand.

Comment: At the moment, I'm not sure how to bend `define_method`. But you can always build your method definition as a string and `class_eval` it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is that not kinda dangerous? Do you know some gems using this pattern so I can check how they deal with it?

Comment: Dangerous only if you allow user input to be eval'ed. If you control what is evaled, then there's no additional danger (you already can do a lot of damage without eval). Rails is using it a lot. For example, https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c6d852854ad068acf7d610808ed501b7d13c7f6/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors_per_thread.rb#L42-L54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as advised I went to `class_eval`.

```rb
class Whatever
  class << self
    def add_method(name, parameters = {})
      class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{name}(#{method_parameters(parameters)})
          #{method_body(parameters)}
        end
      RUBY
    end

    # method_parameters({
    #   foo: { required: false, default: 0 },
    #   bar: { required: true }
    # })
    # => "foo: 0, bar:"
    def method_parameters(parameters)
      parameters.map do |key, options|
        value = options[:required] ? '' : " #{options[:default] || 'nil'}"
        "#{key}:#{value}"
      end.join(', ')
    end

    # method_parameters({
    #   foo: { required: false, default: 0 },
    #   bar: { required: true }
    # })
    # => "[foo, bar]"
    def method_body(parameters)
      "[#{parameters.keys.map(&:to_s).join(', ')}]"
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
params = {
  foo: { required: false, default: 0 },
  bar: { required: true }
}

Whatever.add_method(:hello, params)

Whatever.new.hello(bar: true) # => [0, true]
Whatever.new.hello(foo: 42, bar: true) # => [42, true]
Whatever.new.hello # missing keyword: bar (ArgumentError)
```